# iOS formatting phone numbers from address book

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, abaddressbook

My app uses the user's phone number as unique username, and it also sync all of his contacts so he can send them messages.

So, I need a way to format all the phone numbers I'm getting from the phone's address book.

I need to know for a given number:

1. Country code (if exists).
2. The number itself.

And if the number includes some international call prefix, it should be remove from the number.

So for example if I have a contact with the number

```
014 1 3728834122
```

The format should tell me that the country code is 1 and that the number is `3728834122` (I don't care about the 014 prefix)

What interesting is that the native phone address book seems to know how to format the number, I can see it while typing a new number, it added () or spaces when needed.

So my **question** is:

1. Can I query the native address book for a given number, what's his country code & number?
2. Does anyone knows a good library that do this kind of formatting?

Comment: hi you got the solution of this question ?